# How to return SqlCommand stored procedure executed syntax?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure named `My_StoredProcedure` like this:

```
create proc My_StoredProcedure (val1 int, val2 int)
as
    insert into mytable values (val1,val2)
```

And I need to get this stored procedure syntax if it has wrong in execution

Not get stored procedure name

And this is my code

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("My_StoredProcedure", cn);
cn.open();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("val1",1);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("val2",2);

try
{
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return ???(what stored procedure executed syntax)???;
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you expect to be returned? e.g. do you want the string "My_StoredProcedure (@val1=1, @val2=2)"?

Comment: Do you want the complete stored procedure definition, or something like `My_StoredProcedure @val1=1, @val2=2`?

Comment: @ beargle i want to see all stored procedure like **insert into mytable values (val1,val2)**

Comment: @ richaux i want to see all stored procedure like insert into mytable values (val1,val2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want the definition of the procedure that failed to execute? You can get this by querying `sys.sql_modules`

```
try
{
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var sql = "select top (1) [definition] " +
              "from sys.sql_modules m " +
              "join sys.objects o " +
              "on m.object_id = o.object_id " +
              "where o.name = 'My_StoredProcedure' ";

    var qry = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

    var rdr = qry.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);

    string definition = null;

    while(rdr .Read())
    {
        definition = rdr["definition"].ToString();
    }
}
```

or your query could use `sys.objects`

```sql
SELECT OBJECT_DEFINTION(object_id)
FROM sys.objects
WHERE name = 'My_StoredProcedure' 
AND [type] IN ('P', 'PC')
```

To 'clean' the definition i.e. get rid of `CREATE PROC` is probably easiest done in C# with some regex.